# How do I normalize a weighted scoring grid?

Tags: normalization

I have created a weighted scoring grid that looks something like this

```
        Factor 1 (weight of 5, scored either 3,6 or 9)        Factor 2 (weight of 4, scored either 3, 6 or 9)
```

Question 1
    Score of 6  for Factor 1
    Score of 9  for Factor 2
    Total Score of (5*6)+(4*9)=66

Question 2
    Score of 3   for Factor 1
    Score of 6   for Factor 2
    Total Score of (5*3)+(4*6)=39

How do I put the score of 66 and 39 into a more understandable scale of say 1-10 or 1-20?

Answer (score 1):

Work out the minimum score (5 * 3 + 4 * 3 = 27). Then subtract the minimum and calculate the new maximum (5 * 9 + 4 * 9 - 27) and then divide the result by the maximum. You now have a score between 0 and 1. If you want 0-10 then just multiply by 10. If you want 1-10 then multiply by 9 and add 1.

Comment: Thank you fo your response. mdewey.Just to clarify, when you say 'subtract the minimum', you are saying 'subtract the minimum from each Total Score' , correct? i.e. in the above example, if the minimum score was 15, then for Question 1, I would do (66-15) and then divide that by the maximum, right ?

Comment: +1, but a correction: divide by (max - min) not max.

Comment: @knrumsey if the OP subtracts the minimum first it now is zero so dividing by the maximum is OK. I edited to make that clearer, I hope.

Comment: I have tried again. Thank you for your help @knrunsey. I must have been very tired when I did the first version.